# error message when doing if statement and removing white spaces

Tags: java

Hi for my assignment question:

The parameter passed for the name field must not be null,
and must not be an empty String or a String composed only
of whitespace.  If the argument passed as the parameter is
3 either  null  or  an  empty/whitespace  String,  set  the  field  to
`DEFAULT_POOL_NAME` Otherwise,  format  the  value
correctly (remove the whitespace, capitalize the first letter,
set the rest to lower case) before storing it in the instance
variable.

Here is my code:

```
public Pool(String newName, double newVolumeLitres, double newTemperatureCelsius, double newPH, double newNutrientCoefficient) {
  if (newName != null && newName.trim().length() > 0) {
   name = formatNameTitleCase(newName.trim());
  } else {
   name = DEFAULT_POOL_NAME;
  }
}
```

I am getting an error message that states

```
cannot find symbol - method formatNameTitleCase(java.lang.string)
```

Comment: sorry about the bad paste.

Comment: learn how to format your code

Comment: public Pool (String newName, double newVolumeLitres, double newTemperatureCelsius, double newPH, double newNutrientCoefficient) {                                                                                                                          if (newName != null && newName.trim().length() > 0) {
        name = formatNameTitleCase(newName.trim() );
        
    }
        else {
            name = DEFAULT_POOL_NAME;
        }

Comment: So what I gather is that formatNameTitleCase doesn't exist.

Comment: im guessing ya but its not suppose to im just trying to make first letter capital and rest lower case

Comment: So that's 'pseudocode' and that method doesn't exist and is 'placeholder'? Why would expect it to run

Comment: You have to create method, it wouldn't just magically appear.

Comment: how would i do that? because im trying to remove the whitespaces and capitalize the first letter and rest lowercase

Comment: Kurt, consider checking out my answer. It explains and shows the application of capitalization and removing whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize the first letter, take the substring and set to uppercase, like so:

```
somestring.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + somestring.substring(1);
```

In your case it'd be:

```
String trimmed = newName.trim();

name = trimmed.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + trimmed.substring(1);
```

(I'm assuming `name` is already initialized)

`substring()` takes a certain specified section of a string and captures it. `substring(0, 1)` will get the first character of the word and capitalize it with `toUpperCase()`. `substring(1)` will then take the rest of the string from the first character on and will concatenate it with the capital letter, thus producing the following output. From,

```
"examplestring"
```

to,

```
"Examplestring"
```

I would also recommend utilizing `toLowerCase()` to be extra sure that the rest is lowercase. Finally, I would probably do a try/catch to make sure the string index actually exists. Final code that is 'fail-safe':

```
String trimmed = newName.trim();
try {
    name = trimmed.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + trimmed.substring(1).toLowerCase();
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStrackTrace();
    System.out.println("String was not at least one character!");
}
```

`trim()` only gets rid of trailing whitespaces, so use the `replaceAll()` method like so:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

This replaces all whitespace including things like newlines (\n). It uses a regex (regular expression) to match all whitespace and replaces with nothing.

## TL;DR

Here is the code that removes **all** whitespace and capitalizes the first letter:

```
try {
    name = newName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + newName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    e.printStrackTrace();
    System.out.println("String was not at least one character!");
}
name.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Please consider reading the full post.

## Application

```
public String formatNameTitleCase(String oldName) {
    try {
        name = oldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + oldName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    } catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStrackTrace();
        System.out.println("String was not at least one character!");
        return "failed";
    }
    name.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries for checking whitespace cases.
For example :
Apache common lang jar have StringUtils class.
You can use

StringUtils.isNotBlank(String);

Comment: so its StringUtils.isNotBlank(newName);

Comment: No need for third party libraries

Comment: Yes, in your case, it will be newName

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want.

```
public Pool(String newName, double newVolumeLitres, double newTemperatureCelsius, double newPH, double newNutrientCoefficient) {
    //Removing White spaces
    if(newName!=null) {
        newName = newName.replaceAll(" ", "");
    }
    //Check for empty and null
    if(newName==null || newName.isEmpty()) {
        newName=DEFAULT_POOL_NAME;
    }
    //Setting the first to uppercase and the rest to lower case
    else {
        newName = newName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + newName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ahmed but im not sure what u mean when u said hello from here and yahoo?

Comment: The string variable is your string can be anything.
and DEFAULT_POOL_NAME is any default name you set also.

Comment: I'm Just showing you that if name is "hello FROM HerE" the output will be Hellofromhere , and if the name = null or only white spaces the result will be   the DEFAULT_POOL_NAME which is yahoo here

Comment: oh ok but im suppose to set it to DEFAULT_POOL_NAME.

Comment: You suppose to set it to DEFAULT_POOL_NAME only in the case of empty spaces and null.

Comment: You'll replace string with newName parameter , and DEFAULT_POOL_NAME with your default string.

Comment: so String newName = "";
        String DEFAULT_POOL_NAME = DEFAULT_POOL_NAME;

Comment: my default is name in the parameter i changed to newName and public static final String DEFAULT_POOL_NAME = "Unnamed";

Comment: thank very much ahmed thats what i did before also its just for if(newName!=null)string = newName.replaceAll(" ", ""); the word string is giving me an error that says cannot find variable : variable string